# datePicker shows 1.January

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker, xcode5

I am using Xcode and programming for ios.
I have a datePicker in my application for reservations.
You can't reserve dates that passed.

When I press on datePicker, when it opens, instead of "Today" it shows "Thu 1 Jan".
If I scroll for one day up, it will show "Fri 2 Jan".
But, if I scroll for few day in past, when it comes back to today's date it shows "Today", as it should, and everything works normal from that point.

Even if it says "Thu 1 Jan" if I save date and time, it shows correct date and time.

```
- (void)showDatePicker {
  _orderTableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
  _datePicker.date = _order.scheduleDate;
  _datePicker.minimumDate = [NSDate date];
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
_datePickerView.frameBottom = self.view.frameBottom;
}];
}
```

Every suggestion is more than appreciated.

Edit1: Not sure if relevant, but minimum Date I put as Constraints is 01/01/1970 (that year New Year was on Thursday).

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact same problem and finally realized that the date I was giving the picker was not the date I thought I was giving it (01/01/0001 instead of the current date). Giving it the right date fixed the problem. Note that I am using Xamarin and C# but the concept may be the same.

Answer (score -2):

Select your UIDatePicker in attribute inspector in Date choose current date.This will display your current date.

Comment: Under Attribute inspector I have Date selected as Current Date. 
As I said in question, the problem is only first and second date from start shown as 1.1 and 2.1, rest is all normal, even does dates go back to normal when I break Constraint.